# Query gets data from two different users when I try to get data just from just one user

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I want to get data just from only one specific user but I get data from both users. Why is that? I don't understand. How can I solve this?.

I have three tables:

```
/*User*/

    CREATE TABLE `User` (
    `IDUser` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`IDUser`)
);

/*Category*/

     CREATE TABLE `Category` (
      `IDCategory` CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
      `FK_User` INT NOT NULL,
      `CategoryName` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`IDCategory`, `FK_User`)
    );

/*Product*/

    CREATE TABLE `Product` (
        `IDProduct` VARCHAR(18) NOT NULL,
        `FK_User` INT NOT NULL,
        `ProductName` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
        `FK_Category` CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`IDProduct`, `FK_User`)
    );

ALTER TABLE `Product` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`FK_User`) REFERENCES `User`(`IDUser`);
ALTER TABLE `Product` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`FK_Category`) REFERENCES `Category`(`IDCategory`);
ALTER TABLE `Category` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`FK_User`) REFERENCES `User`(`IDUser`);

insert into User(Name) values('User1');
insert into User(Name) values('User2');

insert into Category(IDCategory,FK_User,CategoryName) values('CT1',1,'Category1User1');
insert into Category(IDCategory,FK_User,CategoryName) values('CT1',2,'Category1User2');
```

If two different users insert both the same product with the same ID:

```
insert into Product values('001',1,'shoe','CT1');
insert into Product values('001',2,'shoe','CT1');
```

Why do I keep getting data from both users if I try a query like this one:

```
SELECT P.IDProduct,P.ProductName,P.FK_Category,C.CategoryName 
FROM Product P inner join Category C on P.FK_Category=C.IDCategory 
WHERE P.FK_User=1
```

this is the result I get:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting two rows because both categories have the same `IDCategory` value which is the value you are `JOIN`ing on. You need to also `JOIN` on the `FK_User` values so that you don't also get `User2`'s category values:

```
SELECT P.IDProduct,P.ProductName,P.FK_Category,C.CategoryName 
FROM Product P 
INNER JOIN Category C ON P.FK_Category=C.IDCategory AND P.FK_User = C.FK_User
WHERE P.FK_User=1
```

Comment: I was going crazy all day long beacuse of this and I didn't see my mistake. Thanks a lot @Nick

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `p.FK_User=C.Fk_User` this condition in your join clause

```
SELECT P.IDProduct,P.ProductName,P.FK_Category,C.CategoryName 
FROM Product P inner join Category C 
on P.FK_Category=C.IDCategory and p.FK_User=C.Fk_User
WHERE P.FK_User=1
```

Answer (score 0):

A `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE` key.  Shouldn't `CategoryID` be unique?  That is, shouldn't `Category` have `PRIMARY KEY(CategoryId)`?

(Check other tables for a similar problem.)